# Trying to divide images in multiple folders to train and test folder, but code is only reading/copying last folder

Tags: python, machine-learning, training-data, test-data

My current dataset has images inside multiple folders, labeled by class.  I want to create a 'train' and 'test' folder, and class folders within those directories.  Then, I want to put 70% of the images in the 'train' folders and 30% of the images in the 'test' folder, like so:

Train Folder 
**Beans folder:**

- img1
- img2
- ...

**Cake folder:**

- img1
- ...

My code to do this right now is this (I'm testing on a tiny dataset right now):

```
classes = ('BEANS', 'CAKE') #'Candy', 'Cereal', 'Chips', 'Chocolate',
          # 'Coffee', 'Corn', 'Fish', 'Flour', 'Honey', 'Jam', 'Juice',
          # 'Milk', 'Nuts', 'Oil', 'Pasta', 'Rice', 'Soda', 'Spices',
          # 'Sugar', 'Tea', 'Tomato Sauce', 'Vinegar', 'Water')

# create sub-folders for each class
OUTPATH = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Dataset\\freiburg_groceries_dataset\\sets'
for x in classes:
    os.makedirs(OUTPATH+'\\train\\'+x, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(OUTPATH+'\\test\\'+x, exist_ok=True)

INPATH = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Dataset\\freiburg_groceries_dataset\\imgs'
filenames = os.listdir(INPATH + '\\' + x)
counts = {x:0 for x in classes}
for x in classes:
    print(len(filenames))
    print(filenames)

testset = len(filenames) / 10 * 0.3 # 30%

for fl in filenames:
    for cl in classes:
        if cl in fl:
            counts[cl] += 1 # increase count +1
            if counts[cl] < testset:
                shutil.move(INPATH + '\\' + x + '\\' + fl, OUTPATH+'\\test\\'+cl+'\\'+fl)
            else:
                shutil.move(INPATH + '\\' + x + '\\' + fl, OUTPATH+'\\train\\'+cl+'\\'+fl)
```

My code creates the folders I need, but then it only reads the `CAKE` folder and ignores the `BEANS` folder.  It also moves all the cake images to the train folder and leaves the cake-->test folder blank, and does not move any of the BEAN images.  Can anyone see where my code is failing to follow the steps to work with the BEANS folder, and to move 30% of cake images to the test folder?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two places where your code is not functioning as intended.

```
OUTPATH = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Dataset\\freiburg_groceries_dataset\\sets'
for x in classes:
    os.makedirs(OUTPATH+'\\train\\'+x, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(OUTPATH+'\\test\\'+x, exist_ok=True)

INPATH = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Dataset\\freiburg_groceries_dataset\\imgs'
filenames = os.listdir(INPATH + '\\' + x) # <------ source of error no. 1 `x` is already defined in the loop and holds the last value that it contained i.e. `cake`
```

corrections needed

```
filenames = []
for x in classes:
    filenames.extend(os.listdir(INPATH + '\\' + x))
```

and the next one at

```
for x in classes:
    print(len(filenames))
    print(filenames)

testset = len(filenames) / 10 * 0.3 # <----- source of error no.2 This is not 30% rather 3 percent only (don't divide by 10).
```

Edit: (the following would be much more simple solution you would be looking for)

```
classes = ('BEANS', 'CAKE')
# create sub-folders for each class
OUTPATH = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Dataset\\freiburg_groceries_dataset\\sets'
INPATH = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Dataset\\freiburg_groceries_dataset\\imgs'

for class in classes:

    train_path = OUTPATH + '\\train\\' + class + '\\'
    test_path  = OUTPATH + '\\test\\' + class + '\\'

    in_path    = INPATH + '\\' + class + '\\'

    os.makedirs(train_path , exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(test_path, exist_ok=True)

    filenames = os.listdir(in_path)

    no_of_pictures = len(filenames)

    test_set = int(len(filenames) * 0.3)
    train_set= len(filenames) - test_set

    test_imgs = filenames[:test_set]
    train_imgs = filenames[test_set:]

    for test_img in test_imgs:
        shutil.move( inpath + test_img, test_path + test_img)
    for train_img in train_imgs:
        shutil.move( inpath + train_img, train_path + train_img)
```

Comment: Changing the calculation worked!  But, using .extend made it try to add images to folders outside their class (e.g., beans00.png --> cake folder), but using this helped:
`
for x in classes:
    filenames = os.listdir(INPATH + '\\' + x)
    print(classes)
    print(len(filenames))
    print(filenames)`

But images are still only getting added to the CAKE folder, so I think there is something wrong with the last loop.